# Service, ExecutorService or something else?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Faced with the question, I have a listener that is triggered when I add a new item to the list, the listener returns the location data:

```
mAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
```

}

Knowing the place data I need to find a location ID, but for that I need to get the info from the online database.

Adding to the list can occur very quickly, and each time will trigger the listener. But the user can close the application, press back button and  so  on. 
It is important for me that all the add location binding  with ID. What is the  best way to do this (searching and binding ID)? Start Service every time or maybe is there another way?

Comment: Start service once, pass intents to it when you need it to do something

Comment: I am using the IntentService, but  if  user will be add  a lot of items to list everytime i start IntentService. What kind of problems can be with this decision? Each time the service executes all service methods or if it is running, it will start immediately with a concrete method?